# How can I use Sinch in my webapp to send reminder to users with clickable link?

Tags: web-applications, push-notification, sinch

I  am developing a progressive **webapp** (PWA) in which i want to send reminder messages to users. The message should contain a link that opens my webapp.  Sinch offers SMS and Instant messaging. Is it possible to achieve when i described with both methods?  If SO how?

Answer (score 0):

You can send sms with us, but you cant send arbitrary push with us.